# How to compare each item from dir with each item from another dir?

Tags: python

The task is to compare students homework SQL files with mentors SQL files.

I've written two functions, which return a two-dimensional array (1st elements are an absolute path, 2nd are a relative). Then I'm going to compare the relative path of students and mentors and execute SQL files (finding using absolute path) if these values are equal

Is there a more elegant realization?

The folder structure of mentors dir:

`Homework (folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql`

The folder structure of students dir:

`├Students Homework (folder)
 ├Student1(folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
 ├Student2(folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql`

"Mentors" function:

```py
def find_mentors_sql(config):

    mentors_sql_abs = []
    mentors_sql_rel = []

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Homework'):
        mentors_sql_abs.extend(path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))
        mentors_sql_rel.extend(path.join(path.basename(dirpath), x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))

    mentors_sql = [[0] * 2 for i in range(len(mentors_sql_abs))]

    iter = 0
    for _ in mentors_sql_abs:
        mentors_sql[iter][0] = mentors_sql_abs[iter]
        iter += 1

    iter1 = 0
    for _ in mentors_sql_rel:
        mentors_sql[iter1][1] = mentors_sql_rel[iter1]
        iter1 += 1

    return mentors_sql
```

"Students" function (the logic is similar to the previous one:

```py
def find_students_sql(config):

    students_sql_abs = []
    students_sql_rel = []

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Students Homework'):
        students_sql_abs.extend(path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))
        students_sql_rel.extend(path.join(path.basename(dirpath), x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))

    students_sql = [[0] * 2 for i in range(len(students_sql_abs))]

    iter = 0
    for _ in students_sql:
        students_sql[iter][0] = students_sql_abs[iter]
        iter += 1

    iter1 = 0
    for _ in students_sql:
        students_sql[iter1][1] = students_sql_rel[iter1]
        iter1 += 1

    return students_sql
```

Comment: In which way you want to improve? Or do you encounter any errors?

Comment: If your code is working, you might want to post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for improvement advice.